# nginx, x-accel-redirect and mime types

Tags: nginx, mime, mime-type

In my nginx 0.8.34 setup I'm using the X-Accel-Redirect feature to control file downloads in the application code while not having the application handle the download itself.

After much pain this now basically works except nginx always returns the file with `text/html` content type.

The default content type is application/octet-stream, specified in the `http` block.

The server block contains, among other things, the definition of the directory where the files are stored:

```
location /files {
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  alias /srv/www/uploads;
  internal;  
}
```

So I specified the content type even here but nothing has changed.

I don't want to set the Content-Type by the application because then I would slow me down (I'd first have to determine it). So ideally nginx would return the correct mimetype based on the file extension (I do include mime.types in the `http` block).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to let nginx guess the right mime type, you juste have to make sure no content-type is returned from your backend server.

```
With django:
    response = HttpResponse()
    response['Content-Type'] = ''
    response['X-Accel-Redirect'] ='/my/file.jpg'
    return response
```

Comment: with tornado: 
tornado.web.RequestHandler.clear(self)
self.set_header('X-Accel-Redirect', redirect_location)
self.clear_header('Content-Type')
as the .clear method sets content-type to text/html

Answer (score 1):

I personally just set application/octet-stream in the application but you **might** be able to use [fastcgi_ignore_headers](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFcgiModule#fastcgi_ignore_headers) to prevent Nginx from using the back-end supplied header.

```
fastcgi_ignore_headers Content-Type;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to server different content types so that images render as images and zip files are offered as a download option. So unfortunately this does not quite solve it.

Comment: Did you try it or are you just assuming it won't work? By ignoring the back-end supplied header it should try to determine it based on the file.

Comment: One cannot ignore `Content-Type`. According to http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFcgiModule#fastcgi_ignore_headers possible values are `X-Accel-Redirect`, `X-Accel-Expires`, `Expires` or `Cache-Control`

Comment: "It is possible to specify headers like" while shitty phrasing does not mean "the possible values are". I have ignored Content-Type before in combination with x-accel-redirect so I don't think it's impossible, though, I'll admit I'm not intimate with the gritty details.

Comment: @MartinFjordvald, tried it and nginx refused to start complaining `nginx: [warn] invalid value "Content-Type" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:27` but `fastcgi_ignore_headers "Expires"` works

Answer (score 1):

with php-fpm:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: ");
    header("X-accel-redirect: (...)");
```

tells php to not send a Content-Type header at all (not even an empty one), and nginx will guess the type for you and add the header :)